# How add id in a angular template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im trying to update this **[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30267172/how-do-i-add-image-in-a-angular-ui-grid-cell)** to put image on one angular grid table:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ui.grid']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    enableSorting: true,
    rowHeight:100,
    columnDefs: [
      { field: 'name' },
      { field: 'company'  },
      { field: 'image', cellTemplate:"<img width=\"50px\" ng-src=\"{{grid.getCellValue(row, col)}}\" lazy-src>"}
    ],
    data:[
      {name:"Name1",company:"Company1",image:"http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/70689.png"},
      {name:"Name2",company:"Company2",image:"http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/70689.png"},
      {name:"Name3",company:"Company3",image:"http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/70689.png"}
      ]
  };

}]);
```

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/awQ7B0WmmZhythlCZmgt?p=preview)**

But Im not sure how `ng-src=\"{{grid.getCellValue(row, col)}}\"` give me `image:` property. What if my data model has several pictures, how he know which one take.

And I want make the image clickeable so I need set `ID={{name}}` and `class` how  can I do that?

```
cellTemplate:"<img ID:{{name}} class="img-click" width=\"50px\" 
               ng-src=\"{{grid.getCellValue(row, col)}}\" lazy-src>"}
```

Comment: `class="img-click"` != `class=\"img-click\"`

Comment: can add `ng-click` on the element template as well, something like `ng-click=clicker_function(row)`

Comment: How would `id` and `class` make it clickable? If they are there to match the selector, this is a bad idea.

Comment: @estus Yes, i was going to make `$(".class").click(function)` that is what i know, if you have better idea, please let me know just trying to learn how solve it.

Comment: @reptilicus I try that, but doesnt work on the [**demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/GSnlblxVpAgFDsaz4S8h?p=preview) can you see if im doing something wrong. I try `<img ng-src=\"img_click()\" width` doesnt seem to recognize the function i create.

Comment: don't use `$(".class")` functions with angular, they aren't angular aware.  use `ng-click` instead.

Comment: @Claies Yes, im working on it, but the function I create isnt recognize yet.  Still trying to understand how the image src is selected in case more than one image there

Comment: and `ng-src=\"img_click()\"` seems weird, since `img_click` sounds like a function you want to call on click, not a function that gets the image source.

Comment: @Claies I need both. The sample already take the image from data model. Still dont know how. And I want to make it clickeable.

Comment: @Claies yes I make a copy mistake ... is `ng-click=\"img_click()\" ` but still doesnt work in my demo. [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/OOPLeBkv0YCFAAgvmCOS?p=preview)

Comment: more than one image for a single item you mean?  like you would have `image` and `image2` in your data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120372/discussion-between-juan-carlos-oropeza-and-claies).

Comment: @Claies Yes, on that sample I can't see how they choose the image. `{{grid.getCellValue(row, col)}}` doesnt specify fieldname.

Comment: it does specify the field name, it's the first parameter in that object.

Comment: @Claies but how that work? first parameter of that object is `name`

Comment: It would be better to restate the question, as it solely applies to Angular UI Grid and not to Angular in general, and to clarify what should be done on click. Your plunker doesn't work, you cannot expect the changes to be visible if the app can't even be initialized. Fortunately, we don't have to fly blind when we've got dev tools. Please, check the console for errors, they are all there.

Comment: @estus the original [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/awQ7B0WmmZhythlCZmgt?p=preview) in the question works ok, is when i try to update it I start getting errors.